# How to clip specific columns of a dataframe to a specified range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to clip the three columns of `c1, c2, c3` to [-1, 1] in df.

That is, values greater than 1. are assigned 1., and values less than -1. are assigned -1..

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

df = pd.DataFrame(rand.uniform(-2, 2, 50).reshape(10, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
print(df)
```

```
          a         b        c1        c2        c3
0  0.547847 -0.920853 -1.836106 -1.933889  1.253081
1  1.651022  0.426543  0.917986  0.174500  1.740290
2  1.263414 -1.989046  1.429617 -1.865658  0.918622
3 -1.297378  1.452716  0.165845 -0.801152 -0.309251
4 -1.886721 -1.502867  0.682498  0.588758  0.461540
5 -0.465290  1.988840  1.923341  0.742168  0.601837
6  0.753787 -0.444314 -1.459614  0.885953  0.101417
7 -0.759032 -0.056659  1.557951  1.736174 -0.568819
8  0.286119 -0.712522  0.377200 -0.648355 -0.433524
9  1.561097 -1.091370  0.492749 -1.663939  1.330577
```

What I want to achieve:

```
          a         b        c1        c2        c3
0  0.547847 -0.920853 -1.       -1.        1.      
1  1.651022  0.426543  0.917986  0.174500  1.      
2  1.263414 -1.989046  1.       -1.        0.918622
3 -1.297378  1.452716  0.165845 -0.801152 -0.309251
4 -1.886721 -1.502867  0.682498  0.588758  0.461540
5 -0.465290  1.988840  1.        0.742168  0.601837
6  0.753787 -0.444314 -1.        0.885953  0.101417
7 -0.759032 -0.056659  1.        1.       -0.568819
8  0.286119 -0.712522  0.377200 -0.648355 -0.433524
9  1.561097 -1.091370  0.492749 -1.        1.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: pandas has a clip method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use pandas build in [clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html)

```
df[['c1','c2','c3']] = df[['c1','c2','c3']].clip(-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

While @ti7 suggestion comes pretty close, it doesn't quite handle the case presented.  This is how I would approach solving this problem.

```
def clip(arr, clip_left, clip_right):
    for id, val in enumerate(arr):
        if val > clip_right:
            arr[id] = 1.0
        elif val < clip_left:
            arr[id] = -1.0
    
    return arr
```

then running

```
cols = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
for c in cols:
    df[c] = clip(df[c], -1.0, +1.0)
print(df)
```

Yields:

```
       a                b          c1          c2        c3
0   0.547847    -0.920853   -1.000000   -1.000000   1.000000
1   1.651022    0.426543    0.917986    0.174500    1.000000
2   1.263414    -1.989046   1.000000    -1.000000   0.918622
3   -1.297378   1.452716    0.165845    -0.801152   -0.309251
4   -1.886721   -1.502867   0.682498    0.588758    0.461540
5   -0.465290   1.988840    1.000000    0.742168    0.601837
6   0.753787    -0.444314   -1.000000   0.885953    0.101417
7   -0.759032   -0.056659   1.000000    1.000000    -0.568819
8   0.286119    -0.712522   0.377200    -0.648355   -0.433524
9   1.561097    -1.091370   0.492749    -1.000000   1.000000
```